# Autolayout requires negative constant to align with superview?

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

There is something strange about my constraints in my storyboard. Any time I want the edges of a subview to align with the view controller's superview (leading, trailing, top, bottom), I have to set the constant to -16. It should be 0, as in there is 0 difference between the superview edge and the subview. However, setting it to 0 effectively gives a +16 buffer between the subview edge and the superview.

Why do i need to set it to -16?

Comment: Are you aligning to superview margins? Select the constraint and look at the inspector information for it.  Do the "First Item" and "Second Item" values end with the word "Margin"?  If so, click on the box for either value and in the dropdown, uncheck the "Relative to margin" option.

Comment: Ah yes. Unchecking 'Relative to margin' and setting the constant to 0 fixes it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any time I want the edges of a subview to align with the view controller's superview

No, that's not what you're doing. That's the problem. You have (accidentally) pinned your constraints to the superview's *margin* instead of its *edge*. There is a crucial difference between this:

[image]

and this (with the Option key held down):

[image]

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize there was this subtle difference. However, when I cntrl+drag from subview to superview, it seems it always defaults to 'Margin'. How did you get the second image you posted?

Comment: Lol. See at the bottom of the first one where it says "Hold Option for alternates"? That's the key: you have to hold the Option key to see the second one. I've filed a bug against this behavior, because it's so hidden and yet it's what people usually want.

Comment: Oh haha. Definitely missed that. Thanks for the help.